# remove clipping

Tags: extrude, loop

I don't know what this problem is, i'm following this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/saxpjudV_88?t=2879). My extrudes leave these artifacts after adding loop cuts. I can add loop cuts to the very corner but that will remove the bevels. I'm wondering what type of problem is this called and how do I practice making cleaner extrudes/bevels.

EDIT added blend file [image]

[image: Image with artifacts]

Comment: The loop cuts look "good enough" Have you tried removing doubles? Is the mesh manifold?

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: It looks to me like deleting the face and filling it might fix this problem.
Edit: Do I put this in comments? (I'm new to Blender Stack Exchange)

Comment: @moonboots added the blend file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your topology is doing things wrong. You are trying to add more loops everywhere against the flow of your shape in hopes that it will eventually work. And theoretically it will eventually work, but will require more subdivision and fighting. It's fine for mesh you don't care about or see in the background of a render.
But it will not do if you want a clean result, and the issue with such a method is precisely that you are working against your shapes, not with them. And you will create irregularities that will show up at some point when you don't want to.

It's really visible when you disable your subdivision modifier's optimal display:

[image: raw mesh]

It's pinching in places that should just be plain flat, it's creating mesh density where there could be literally no mesh at all without being noticed.

Also, in your context, if you want to create edge loops manually, don't use a bevel on top of it. Either one of them is fine, both are redundant.

---

#### Going back to a raw mesh

Let's remove the bevel modifier for now, and also make better use of the mirror modifier by deleting the back facing parts and enabling the mirror on Y so that we really only have to worry about a fourth of the mesh.

Then, in *Edge* selection, select everything and hit <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve*. It will get rid of any edges that aren't necessary to define a shape, which help to understand what's going on in your mesh:

[image: raw mesh]

### Building a sane geometry

From there, you can try to make a new topology. Try to think about how your shapes flow, the directions they take, and try to make your topology help that.

If we think about it, your shape it basically a long rectangle that someone bent in a few places. (It's actually how it's made in real life).

So you could follow the same logic with your topology, which would look something like this:

[image: flow topology]

If we look at the topology with the subdivision ON:
[image: subdivided flow topology]

Sure, the edges aren't as sharp, but we didn't create irregularities nor "new" shapes. Which means: from there, you can basically just slide parts around or add simple edge loops, and it will be fine!

We have only two poles here, at the "outer" edges:

[image: outer poles]

We could do without them but I chose to use them because:

- poles are totally fine on flat surfaces
- they allow us to add more edges around the outer edges, making it easier to sharpen them without adding more edges elsewhere.

Comment: This is true, I'm a Pole and I spend most of my time on flat surfaces.

Comment: Thank you for the concise answer. Topology is wrong and I need to just study that in general.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I spat my coffee through my nose, thanks! ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Answer (score 2):

The *Bevel* modifier creates extra edges that are somehow curved by the *Subdivision Surface*, do you really need this *Bevel* modifier? You could remove it and simply add this edge loop to sharp the angle:

[image]

Comment: The tutorial had bevel and subdivision and resulted in a smooth bevel.

Comment: @goda one way to use a bevel that doesn't break the subdivision after it, is to bevel all edges, indiscriminately - this way no ngons are created, which the Catmull-Clark algorithm dislikes.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is used for, but if you add the edge loop I show it will fix your problem

Comment: I'm not sure either, i'm going to do tutorials specifically on bevels and subdivision separately. That will probably make my smooth brain understand this.